# How can an android app fetch views and query the database from a Django based site?

Tags: java, android, python, django, xml-rpc

What is the best way an android app can fetch views and query the database from a Django based site?

I am developing a website using Django framework. The web/mobile service comes with a Android app that authenticates the user, fetchs user-related authorized data, map locations from database and views from the website and displays them on the android device.

So far I have been contemplating to use XML-RPC to do this but I am not sure if this is the best solution.

For XML-RPC client, I am using the following library:
http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/

An for the server I am using this python code:
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/XML-RPC

I would like to know if there's a better or standard solution for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an API for your site. Use TastyPie or Piston. Your API should be able to accept a user token to get user-specific data.

From your Android app, have the user give a username & password. You send the username & password to your site's API then return a token. The Android app will use that token to access the API from now on.

Here's an article on accessing an API and parsing the JSON output: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: + for TastyPie, - for Piston. Really, don't use Piston anymore. It's outdated.